# Can I 301 redirect multiples URLs to one page without risking a search engine penalty such as duplicate content?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, canonical-url

I have multiples url's directing to a single page, ex:

```
www.example.com.br/phone-calls-right-now
www.example.com.br/phone-calls-for-yesterday
www.example.com.br/phone-calls-cheaper
www.example.com.br/phone-calls-for-free
```

and redirecting 301 to this single page:

```
www.example.com.br/phone-calls
```

This is acceptable? the search engine see like a duplicated content?
If it's an empty page, there is an way to put an `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">` and let it there?

Comment: If you are looking for an advantage in the search engines by having so many URLs, with the redirect this will not do what you think it will do. Otherwise, if your motive is something else, then I cannot see a problem. Cheers!!

Comment: Dismantling a bunch a spammy pages by creating a centralized resource that is actually meant for users sounds like a good plan.

Answer (score 3):

This is acceptable, and unless something else is going on, should not result in a penalty.

You have four phone-related URL's, and they're permanently redirecting to a single phone-related URL. This is semantically proper, as search engines are concerned. If they were not related, it might constitute a problem, but as it stands, there's nothing illegal here.

Duplicate content would occur if you had two pages that were almost identical in their content in the SERPs.

If you were to use a "noindex, follow" meta robots tag, your old URL would not redirect the user to an updated page, and would still be accessible if a hyperlink to the old one existed somewhere in your content or navigation. If the page is empty, however, your concern comes down to, does a link to it live somewhere on your website, and do you want to hide it from the search index or also from your website users? But that depends on your specific case.

Comment: Well, if you redirect or noindex, the keyword will not work - you'll have a cleaner SERP profile, that's all. But if you have no "calls for free" but advertise it anyway, it will only be detrimental. If you don't offer that product or deal, that's not a keyword you should be shooting to rank for. Instead, work on ranking for the terms for products you offer, such as "phone calls to [wherever]" or "cheap phone plans" or whatever it is.

Comment: See if I missed the point. So having those urls that will only serve to redirect to a main page(that I would like to rank), is unificient and detrimental?... I think we use this links to engage people that is searching for the product that we don't sell anymore, and see that we still selling a related product.

Comment: Redirecting is fine, and noindexing is fine, depending on what your goals are for the page, and how you're using (or not using) the page. I was referring to your previous question of trying to rank for keywords that advertise something you don't offer. Meaning, if you don't have "calls for free," you shouldn't be ranking for that. Either a 301 or a noindex will take care of that.